# Multi Column comboBox but when select the value should be Id

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, ado.net, multiple-columns

i have the done following coding, unable to get the it working.. 
i have a Table with Id, Product, FolderPath. 
i have a comboBox2 where i need two column of data from above table "Id" & "Product" to been shown in comboBox2. Now if i select a Row from comboBox2 i need the textBox1 and textBox2 to be filled with "Product" and "FolderPath" based on the comboBox2 selection. 
Like even though the comboBox2 shows "Id" & "Product" internally the value has to be "Id". 
Following are my code; can someone help me on this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO; 
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        string connString;
        SqlConnection conn;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ifz001;";
            conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();
            Load_Products();
        }
        void Load_Products()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FileFolderPath", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Product"].ToString());
                    comboBox2.ValueMember = dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception lp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(lp.Message);
            }
        }
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*try
            {*/

            var pix = "SELECT * FROM FileFolderPath WHERE Id = '" + comboBox2.ValueMember + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pix, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                PID.Text = dr["Product"].ToString();
                PPath.Text = dr["FolderPath"].ToString();

            }
            /*}
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }*/
        }
```

Comment: if i am not wrong CB display one column. if you want to expand multi columns , need to use listView control

Comment: [ValueMember docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.valuemember?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewComboBoxCell_ValueMember)

Answer (score 0):

Achieved using below code changes:

```
 void Load_Products()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FileFolderPath", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string pid = dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString() as string;
                string p = dt.Rows[i]["Product"].ToString();

                comboBox2.Items.Add(p);
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = p;
                comboBox2.ValueMember = pid.ToString() as string;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception lp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lp.Message);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var ppat = "SELECT * FROM FileFolderPath WHERE Id = '" + comboBox2.SelectedIndex + "' ++1";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ppat, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                PID.Text = dr["Id"].ToString();
                PPath.Text = dr["FolderPath"].ToString();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```